# Proving a part of Sylow's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non abelian group such that $p^n|o(G)$, where $p$ is a prime and $n\gt 1$, then there exists a subgroup of $G$ having order $p^n$.

**Proof:** I have taken $n\gt 1$ as $n=0$ is trivial case and $n=1$ case follows by Cauchy's theorem. Let's use induction on $o(G)$.

**Base case:** $o(G)=1$. The result is true vacuously.

**Induction hypothesis:** Let the statement be true for all groups with order $\lt o(G)$.

If $H$ is any proper subgroup of $G$ such that $p^n|o(H)$ then by Induction hypothesis $H$ has a subgroup $H'$ such that $o(H')=p^n$.

So assuming that no proper subgroup of $G$ has order divisible by $p^n$, it follows by class equation for $G$:

$$o(G)=o(Z(G))+\sum_{a\notin Z(G)}\frac {o(G)}{o(N(a)}.\tag 1$$ (Since $G$ is non abelian, it is plain that $\exists a\in G\setminus Z(G).$)

$p^n|o(G)\implies p^n|\frac {o(G)}{o(N(a)}.o(N(a))\implies p^n|\frac {o(G)}{o(N(a)}.$ (by $(1)$)

It follows by class equation above that $p^n|o(Z(G))$, which is a contradiction as it violates $(1)$.

It follows by contradiction that $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $p^n$.

It follows by induction that the result is true for all finite groups.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the step $p^n\mid \frac {o(G)}{o(N(a)}.o(N(a))\implies p^n\mid \frac {o(G)}{o(N(a)}$. Does it involve the assumption that $p^n$ does not divide the order of any proper subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier: Yes, I tried to indicate the same by "by $(1)$".

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the fact that if $a\mid bc$ and $(a,b)=1$, then $a\mid c$. But that's not the case here. It might happen that, for example, $p\mid o(N(a))$.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier: You’re absolutely correct. I made a mistake there. Thanks a lot for helping me out. :)

Comment: Why are you assuming that $G$ is non-abelian? That is unnecessary and irrelevant. It also invalidates your induction, because a proper subgroup $H$ of a non-abelian group could be abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Because I separately handled abelian case and thought that class equation in case of abelian will not have summation corresponding to $a\notin Z(G)$. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: OK, but you cannot apply the induction hypothesis to the subgroup $H$, because it might be abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I didn't think of that. I see it now- the induction hypothesis that I am using includes only non-abelian groups but I can make my induction hypothesis stronger by saying that.... Ah I see, that's why you mentioned considering G as non abelian is irrelevant. Thanks a lot.